# Fragment doesn't receive channel event sent from ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm trying to show a Snackbar in MainFragment when I click a button inside DialogFragment.
When I call the send event function (in ViewModel) from the dialog class nothing happens. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but other functions which do similar things in the MainFragment work just fine.

In ViewModel, the `clearInput()` function which clears the editText in MainFragment works but `onEditNoteClicked()` doesn't work and nothing happens when I call it.

**NoteOptionsDialog** class:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NoteOptionsDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private val viewModel: NotesViewModel by viewModels()

private fun setupClickListeners(view: View) {
        view.bottom_options_edit.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.onEditNoteClicked()
            dismiss()
        }
    }
```

**NotesViewModel** class:

```
@HiltViewModel
class NotesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val noteDao: NoteDao,
    private val preferencesManager: PreferencesManager,
    private val state: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

private val notesEventChannel = Channel<NotesEvent>()
    val notesEvent = notesEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

fun onSaveNoteClick() {

        val newNote = Note(noteText = noteText, noteLabelId = labelId.value)
        createNote(newNote)
    }

private fun createNote(newNote: Note) = viewModelScope.launch {
        noteDao.insertNote(newNote)
        clearInput()
    }

private fun clearInput() = viewModelScope.launch {
        notesEventChannel.send(NotesEvent.ClearEditText)
    }

fun onEditNoteClicked() = viewModelScope.launch {
        notesEventChannel.send(NotesEvent.ShowToast)
    }

fun onNoteSelected(note: Note, view: View) = viewModelScope.launch {
        notesEventChannel.send(NotesEvent.ShowBottomSheetDialog(note, view))
    }

sealed class NotesEvent {
        object ClearEditText : NotesEvent()
        object ShowToast : NotesEvent()  
        data class ShowBottomSheetDialog(val note: Note, val view: View) : NotesEvent()
    }
```

**NotesFragment** class:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NotesFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home), NotesAdapter.OnNoteItemClickListener,
    LabelsAdapter.OnLabelItemClickListener {

private val viewModel: NotesViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.notesEvent.collect { event ->
                when (event) {

                    is NotesViewModel.NotesEvent.ShowBottomSheetDialog -> {
                        NoteOptionsDialog().show(childFragmentManager, null)
                    }

                    is NotesViewModel.NotesEvent.ClearEditText -> {
                        et_home_note.text.clear()
                    }
                    is NotesViewModel.NotesEvent.ShowToast -> {
                        Snackbar.make(requireView(), "Snack!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add code where `notesEvent` is consumed? Since `clearInput()` and `onEditNoteClicked()` are basically the same function, the problem is not in code shown here. How do you check for `ClearEditText` and how do you check for `ShowToast`?

Comment: maybe... `NotesViewModel by activityViewModels()`?

Comment: The only difference is, `clearInput()` is called from the ViewModel and the `onSaveNoteClick()` is called from MainFragment. but the `ShowToast` is called from a dialogFragment. I added more codes @Michiel

Comment: You're using `by viewModels()`, which means that each fragment is getting an instance tied to that particular fragment (i.e., the `NoteOptionsDialog` has a completely independent copy of your ViewModel compared to the instance in your `NotesFragment`). Is that what you want? How are these two fragments related to one another?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that's how it works when I use `by viewModels()`! I thought both fragments are using the same ViewModel and I can call functions or send data from one to another with that ViewModel. It's a note app and when user clicks a note item in the main fragment, the dialog appears and gives him options like edit, etc... I'd appreciate it if you tell me what's the correct way to do this @ianhanniballake

Comment: Can you include that code that launches the dialog? And explain how the "main fragment" relates to this `NotesFragment`?

Comment: By "Main Fragment" I meant the `NotesFragment`. Sorry if I misled you. I added the code that launches the dialog. The process is like this:  There's a click listener interface in recyclerview adapter. when user clicks on an item, `NotesFragment` calls the `onNoteSelected` in ViewModel. Then ViewModel tells the `NotesFragment` to launch the dialog. @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. For fragments, I should have used `by activityViewModels()` instead of `by viewModels()`

```
private val viewModel: NotesViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked and saved my time.
Want to make it more clear, we need to use activityViewModels() in DialogFragment and DialogHostFragment both. Using only in one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

initialize viewmodel like below in fragments for sharing same instance

```
private val viewModel: NotesViewModel by activityViewModels()
```